# Scan network for all devices

Tags: networking, cisco, local-area-network, nmap

I'm running into a small issue with a network, when I scan it using either nmap or even Fing for android, I can only get the router, and my device, even though I know other devices are connected. This happens on a network using Routerboard hardware and also 2 other networks which both use Cisco Meriaki. I wish to research this further but I don't know what this is called or how to get around it, a name for this network "zoning" system would be great thanks!

Comment: On our old HP access points you could block peer to peer traffic. If that is happening on your network, you would only see hard wired devices (the router but no wireless devices) - could that be it?

Comment: Possibly, however, the network setup seems to be a meshed-type systems, the networks having SSIDS following <company>AP<number> e.g. mynetwork ap5.

Comment: I've figured it out, it's called Client Isolation